# Maven GAE Plugin using JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jdo

I'm using Maven GAE plugin with JDO, I started with jappstart example (https://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/pom.xml), but for some reason classes are not enhanced when I run gae:run command, even I have configured enhancement.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <mappingIncludes>**/jdo/*.class</mappingIncludes>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
        <api>JDO</api>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>                     
            <phase>compile</phase>                      
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-ec</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Exception:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Persistent class "Class com.my.Entity does not seem to have been enhanced.  You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something wrong with my mappings includes. Now it works if entities are in package that has last name entity (example com.my.app.entity):

```
<mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>
```